# Bootstrap 4 datapicker.js not included

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap V4 for my new website seeing that it is in Alpha.

However I cannot see that it has datepicker.js in its build.

Does anyone know if this will be included in V4? If not can anyone recommend a good datepicker?

Comment: For those that end up here: https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/

Comment: Just ensure you have cal.gif or/and cal-grey.gif file available in Project\Content\themes\base\images\media\  datepicker.js working fine for me with Bootstrap4

Comment: **Bootstrap 4** - The datepicker plugin that supports Bootstrap 4 is https://codeply.com/p/kS0t1Ko61K also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046792/

Comment: datepickers mentioned in the comments do not show the calendar when clicking on input. this one does https://gijgo.com/datepicker/example/bootstrap-4

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Maybe you want to try this: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

It's a flexible datepicker widget in the Bootstrap style.

Comment: Could you post your working CSS? The datepicker itself works with bootstrap 4 but it is unstyled.

Comment: @RAC Update, as of today it looks like there are some (unstable) releases of this that worked with Bootstrap 4 very well for me https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.0-RC3

Comment: There is a "today" button, but I'm not seeing a time selector @EricMilliot-Martinez https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#todaybtn

Answer (score 52):

You can use this and then you can add just a `class` form from bootstrap. 
<sup>*(does not matter which version)*</sup>

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label >Begin voorverkoop periode</label>
 <input type="date" name="bday" max="3000-12-31" 
        min="1000-01-01" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label >Einde voorverkoop periode</label>
 <input type="date" name="bday" min="1000-01-01"
        max="3000-12-31" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: this is not a bootstrap control but the browsers datepicker (html5 date input, it is not available in every browser! see https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime)

Comment: Will not work on safari and IE 11 or earlier

Comment: The very reason I'm looking for a boostrap4 datepicker is because I have `<input type="date"` in my project and my browser (chromium) is telling me that
_[Deprecation] '-webkit-appearance: listbox' for elements other than listbox select is deprecated and will be removed in M79, around December 2019. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5070237827334144 for more details._
As December 2019 is starting week tomorrow, thought I needed an alternative!

Comment: I did find a maven dependency: 
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.pingcheng</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap4-datetimepicker</artifactId>
    <version>4.17.45</version>
</dependency>`
which I hope will do what I want, just have to find out how to use it now!

Comment: This does not bind the value from ASP.NET MVC. Do i need to pass set the value manually in JS?

Answer (score 8):

Most of bootstrap datepickers as I write this answer are rather buggy when included in Bootstrap 4.
In my view the least code adding solution is a jQuery plugin.
I used this one https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/ - you can see its usage here: https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/
It sure is not as smooth as the whole BS interface, but it only requires its css and js files along with jQuery which is already included in bootstrap.

Comment: It's true, i try some gem and lib: https://github.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4 but it's so buggy

Comment: Yeaah.... tempusdominus has lot of errors