# Bootstrap DatePicker - Onchange

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, datepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using the [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) plugin. When the user chooses a date, I want to update various parts of my UI. I'm basically trying to create a function that is called when the date changes. However, I've been unsuccessful in my attempts. Currently, I'm trying the following

```
$('#myDatePicker').datetimepicker({
  change: function() {
    alert('date has changed!');
  }                  
});
```

Unfortunately, the `change` function never fires. How do I call a function when the date is changed in the date picker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Bootstrap 4**

The eonasdan datepicker plugin is no longer supported in Bootstrap 4, but there is a new plugin: https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4

> "Tempus Dominus is the successor to the very popular Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker"

To detect the change event, use:

```
$("#datetimepicker1").on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) {
    if (e.oldDate !== e.date) {
        alert('You picked: ' + new Date(e.date).toLocaleDateString('en-US'))
    }
})
```

Datepicker demo: https://codeply.com/p/kS0t1Ko61K

---

**Bootstrap 3** (original answer)

According to [the docs](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange), the event is `dp.change`:

```
$('#myDatePicker').datetimepicker().on('dp.change',function(e){
    console.log(e)
})
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/5cBJkEHiAt

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
$("#myDatePicker").datetimepicker().on('changeDate', function(e) {
    alert('date has changed!');
});
```

Bootstrap doc reference: [`changeDate`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate)

Comment: Readers - There is a Bootstrap datetimepicker and a Bootstrap datepicker.  And this often leads to confusion on event and option names, e.g., this answer is for datepicker whereas the question was about datetimepicker.

Answer (score 1):

For the Bootstrap datepicker the event is changeDate in case people are looking for that: [Docs](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate)

```js
$("input[name='Date']").datepicker().on('changeDate', function (e) {
  console.log(e); //Where e contains date, dates and format
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input name="Date"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
OnChange : Function(data)
{
valueAccessor()(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.